# Multiple nodes returning 500 errors for custom script query

Tags: elasticsearch

Everything was working fine then I reindexed things and suddenly 3/5 nodes started giving an error. Obviously this is also causing only 2/3 of my results to come back properly. This is only happening for custom search query. The code nor the jar changed between when things were working and when they weren't.

Note: Regular filtered multi_match search queries are working just fine.

I have tried:

1. Deleting all indexes and reindexing all data
2. Stopping and starting Elasticsearch
3. Recompiling my custom script
4. Tried the search query 50+ times (Half in Java and half with CURL)

Pastebin is the errors appearing in console: http://pastebin.com/1iq3M6fk

Search query being performed (this has worked for days now and is untouched):

```
{
  "query": {
    "custom_score": {
      "query": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "italian",
          "fields": [
            "name",
            "tags"
          ]
        }
      },
      "script": "customscript",
      "params": {
        "lat": 40.76405282025,
        "lon": -73.972994269042
      },
      "lang": "native"
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the response I'm getting when doing the above query:

```
{
  "took": 225,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 2,
    "failed": 3,
    "failures": [
      {
        "status": 500,
        "reason": "RemoteTransportException[Failed to deserialize exception response from stream]; nested: TransportSerializationException[Failed to deserialize exception response from stream]; nested: StreamCorruptedException[unexpected end of block data]; "
      },
      {
        "status": 500,
        "reason": "RemoteTransportException[Failed to deserialize exception response from stream]; nested: TransportSerializationException[Failed to deserialize exception response from stream]; nested: StreamCorruptedException[unexpected end of block data]; "
      },
      {
        "status": 500,
        "reason": "RemoteTransportException[Failed to deserialize exception response from stream]; nested: TransportSerializationException[Failed to deserialize exception response from stream]; nested: StreamCorruptedException[unexpected end of block data]; "
      }
    ]
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 548,
    "max_score": 16.027588,
    "hits": [
      {
        ...
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Below is the custom script being used in the above query (It has a factory as well):

```
import org.elasticsearch.common.Nullable;
import org.elasticsearch.script.ExecutableScript;
import org.elasticsearch.script.NativeScriptFactory;
import org.elasticsearch.script.AbstractDoubleSearchScript;
import org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.geo.GeoPointDocFieldData;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.Math;

public class CityMapsCustomScript extends AbstractDoubleSearchScript {

    double lat;
    double lon;

    public CityMapsCustomScript(@Nullable Map<String, Object> params) {
        lat = ((Double) params.get("lat")).doubleValue();
        lon = ((Double) params.get("lon")).doubleValue();
    }

    @Override
    public double runAsDouble() {
        double distance = ((GeoPointDocFieldData) doc().field("location")).distance(lat, lon);
        String str = doc().field("_type").getStringValue();
        float score = score();

        if (str.equals("business")) {
            return -distance + (double) score;
        } else {
            return Double.parseDouble(doc().field("_boost").getStringValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: I am on elasticsearch 0.19.11 and so are my java libraries.

Comment: Bump, having the same issue